# Eclipse Luna UI rendering in Linux

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, fedora

I installed Eclipse Luna in Fedora 19 and facing the following problems.

1. Tab headers seems to be big compared to windows installations. I googled and edited .gtkrc-2.0 file in home directory which made tabs smaller. But I'm using High Contrast appearance instead of GTK, to get the dark background. But again the tabs appears big. What is the script I have use or edit to solve this problem.
2. I'm using Dark theme the selection of item in tree is not highlighting. How to solve this ?
3. Tool bar icons seems to be big how to reduce their size?

Comment: What build of Luna? The final release of Luna is not due until next month but you could try release candidate 3 which has just become available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start your Eclipse with this .bash script. It will fix the theme bug. It worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

export SWT_GTK3=0
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
./eclipse -showlocation
```

Answer (score 3):

In Linux Mint Cinnamon 2.6 Eclipse Mars I was able to get correct tab heights by putting the following in the launcher on the menu:

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse --launcher.GTK_version 2
```

Comment: That soled my problem, with Gnome3 in Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you. BTW, how did you found that out?

Answer (score 2):

Go to plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.0.v20140527-2218\css in plugins folder in eclipse directory. You should find there css files. I'm not sure which one is set in Luna as default. So you need find it out and change part `.MPartStack` add `swt-tab-height: 20px; font-size: 8;` with desired parameters.

//edit
Another thing that one my find useful - hiding 'x' on tabs:

```
CTabItem {
 swt-show-close: false !important;
}
```

Comment: Setting swt-tab-height: 20px; makes the minimse and maximize icons on the right of the navigation header tiny... any value lower than 24 triggers this issue. Any know a work around?