# How to change toolbars thick on eclipse? (Manjaro Linux - XFCE)

Tags: linux, eclipse

so I want to make eclipse to look a little more "compact", this, referring to the toolbar thickness. I've changed the tabs width and font size following the instructions here: [Eclipse Luna UI rendering in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966488/eclipse-luna-ui-rendering-in-linux)

I'd like to know if there's a way to change also that "gap" on the toolbars so I can get a little more space.

Here's a SS of my eclipse running: http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/ss-1138171.png

and I want to remove or reduce that gap I'm putting on red, any help/comment would be nice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since eclipse 4.x you can modify the look and fill of controls and workspaces using `CSS`. See this [Eclipse 4 CSS Styling- Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html) it should help.